# Firebase migration for China

Tags: amazon-web-services, firebase, great-firewall-of-china

I have an app and website working perfectly on Firebase. I use various services, namely Realtime Database, Cloud Functions, FCM, Storage, and Hosting. **I now need my services to work in China** where Firebase appears to be banned. Rebuilding my whole systems to work with AWS or similar in order to juggle the two / do a full migration would be a huge nightmare. Does anyone know of a solution for this?

My first thought was to essentially setup a VPN but I read that this would not be allowed and eventually my services would be blacklisted. Any suggestions?

**EDIT**

Hi this is not a duplicate... I am asking for the easiest way to deal with this issue. For instance if there is any tool do so such a migration or a way to setup a legal VPN etc...

Comment: You might want to try posted to a discussion board to look for options rather than Stack Overflow.  Recommendations for solutions are off topic.

Comment: @DougStevenson fair enough although I really don't want to leave Firebase and I feel like the only place to find people who might actually conjure up a good solution is here but que sera sera...

Comment: I'd try the Firebase subreddit.